# Should I use Elastic Beanstalk Dns name directly from application

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am deploying a webservice (rather a website) with AWS Elastic Beanstalk, this is then used by client application, and I shall proably make the webserver servers name configurable in the application in case it has to be moved.

Should I just refer to the EB Dns name (i.e companyname@elasticbeanstalk.com) from my application or am I meant to reference it indirectly through some other name, such as a domain I could own like webservice-mycompany.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the elastic-beanstalk IP, but this could change if you wanted to launch a new environment for some reason. But if you can change your app and update this, then this dns is fine.

Or you could us route 53 to create a DNS to provide to your app, and you can set it up to resolve to your elasticbeanstalk dns. This way you would never have to change your application and can control everything from the console.

http://aws.amazon.com/route53/

Comment: Ah yes because the IP is associated with the 'Environment' rather than the 'Application', so if the environment is load balanced the IP hides the multiple EC2 instances serving the request but if I decide I need more powerful EC2 instances then I would have a different IP for the new environment required, and difficult to communicate that with my customers , so sounds like route53 is the way to go.

Comment: Also if you can launch a new environment with a different name say "companyname-staging@elasticbeanstalk.com" and then do a SwapCNAME to flip the cname of your two environments. See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/APIReference/API_SwapEnvironmentCNAMEs.html. More about Blue Green deployments: http://www.thoughtworks.com/insights/blog/implementing-blue-green-deployments-aws